# How to elegantly check for equality in a hierarchy of classes which have a common base class that holds a primary key?

Tags: c#, equality

**Background**

I have a base class which holds an integer ID that is used for ORM (Microsoft Entity Framework).  There are about 25 classes derived from this, and the inheritance hierarchy is up to 4 classes deep.

**Requirement**

I need to be able to test if an object in this hierarchy is equal to another object. To be equal it is necessary but not sufficient for the IDs to be the same.  For example, if two `Person` objects have different IDs then they are not equal, but if they have the same ID then they may or may not be equal.

**Algorithm**

In order to implement the C# `Equals` method you have to check that:

- The Supplied object is not null.
- It must be of the same type as `this` object
- The `ID`s must match

In addition to this, all other attributes must be compared, except in the special case where the two objects are identical.

**Implementation**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// An object which is stored in the database
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class DatabaseEntity
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The unique identifier; if zero (0) then the ID is not assigned
        /// </summary>
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (ReferenceEquals(obj, this))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (obj.GetType() != GetType())
            {
                return false;
            }

            DatabaseEntity databaseEntity = (DatabaseEntity)obj;
            if (ID != databaseEntity.ID)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return EqualsIgnoringID(databaseEntity);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return ID;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check if this object is equal to the supplied one, disregarding the IDs
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="databaseEntity">another object, which should be of the same type as this one</param>
        /// <returns>true if they are equal (disregarding the ID)</returns>
        protected abstract bool EqualsIgnoringID(DatabaseEntity databaseEntity);
    }

    public class Person : DatabaseEntity
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public override bool EqualsIgnoringID(DatabaseEntity databaseEntity)
        {
            Person person = (Person)databaseEntity;
            return person.FirstName == FirstName && person.LastName == LastName;
        }
    }

    public class User: Person
    {
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public override bool EqualsIgnoringID(DatabaseEntity databaseEntity)
        {
            User user = (User)databaseEntity;
            return user.Password == Password;
        }
    }
```

**Comments**

The feature of this solution that I dislike the most is the explicit conversions. *Is there an alternative solution, which avoids having to repeat all the common logic (checking for null, type etc) in each class?*

Comment: You should probably override the `==` and `!=` operators when overriding `Equals`. To avoid explicit casts, you can use generics - make `DatabaseEntity` generic, and use the generic type argument as the type argument in `EqualsIgnoringId`. If the class isn't sealed, you need to keep the generic argument going as long as you need to (e.g. `Person` should probably still be generic, and `abstract`).

Comment: The bigger problem you're going to run into is `GetHashCode`.  You're going to have to compute a hash code _for each type_ that will guarantee to return the same hash code for "equal" objects.  I think your last equality requirement will make that very, very difficult.

Comment: @DStanley I just use the ID for `GetHashCode`.  Two equal objects must by definition have the same ID and thus the same hash code so this is not a problem.

Comment: @PaulRichards I misread it as objects with equal properties were "equal" _regardless_ of the ID.  In that case hashing the ID may be fine.  Why the check of all of the properties?  Can you have objects with the same ID but different property values?

Comment: @DStanley yes they can, an object can be cloned (deep copied) and modified, it might have the same ID but is a different object when it is in volatile memory.

Comment: @Luaan are you able to post some code, please?  I've tried using generics and I can't get the code to compile.  It would be ok if I had a flat hierarchy with everything inheriting from `DatabaseEntity`.  However this is not the case.  Some of the classes that are derived from `DatabaseEntity` have derived classes themselves; some of these are abstract but others have instances.

Comment: Yeah, that's usually a dead giveaway of bad design. Objects don't really map well to real world hierarchies - tough luck. They're not supposed to be used that way anyway, but it's not like I can actually give you a nicer alternative :D The only thing I can tell you is that over years of developing various CRM and similar systems, I've never resolved this problem in a way that wasn't messy to some extent.

Comment: Couldn't you just check for type equality in DataBaseEntry.Equals(object obj)? This would make the casting a non-problem. Or am I missunderstanding the issue?  
And shouldn't you add a base.Equals check to the implementation of Person.EqualsIgnoringId?

Comment: @TimPohlmann type equality is checked for in my implementation.  But this doesn't solve the whole problem because although the types of the two objects are the same, it doesn't mean that their attributes have the same values.  

I don't like virtual methods which have an implicit requirement that implementing them must call a base method as this call can be missed off and that can lead to bugs.

Comment: What about a method that checks the equality of all properties using obj.GetType().GetProperties()?

Comment: @TimPohlmann this would probably work - I will have a think.  Not every attribute should be compared in all my classes.  It might be possible to facilitate this using attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems simpler if instead of using `abstract`, you just keep overriding the `Equals` method for subclasses. Then you can extend like this:

```
public class Person : DatabaseEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (!base.Equals(other))
            return false;
        Person person = (Person)other;
        return person.FirstName == FirstName && person.LastName == LastName;
    }
}
```

You have to cast to `Person`, but this works with relatively few lines of code and with long hierarchies without any worries. (Because you already checked for the runtime types being the same in the very root of the hierarchy, you don't even have to do a `as Person` with a null check.)

---

As mentioned in the comments, with the above approach you can't stop evaluating (short-circuit) if you know for certain `this` is equal to `other`. (Although you do short-circuit if you know for sure `this` is *not* equal to `other`.) For example, if `this` has reference equality with `other`, you can short-circuit because there's no doubt that an object is equal to itself.

Being able to return early would mean that you can skip a lot of checks. This is useful if the checks are expensive.

To allow `Equals` to short-circuit `true` as well as `false`, we can add a new equality method that returns `bool?` to represent three states:

- `true`: `this` is definitely equal to `other` without any need to check derived classes' properties. (Short-circuit.)
- `false`: `this` is definitely not equal to `other` without any need to check derived classes' properties. (Short-circuit.)
- `null`: `this` might or might not be equal to `other`, depending on derived classes' properties. (**Do not** short-circuit.)

Since this doesn't match the `bool` of `Equals`, you need to define `Equals` in terms of `BaseEquals`. Each derived class checks its base class' `BaseEquals` and chooses to short circuit if an answer is already definite (`true` or `false`) and if not, find out if the current class proves inequality. In `Equals`, then, a `null` means that no class in the inheritance hierarchy could determine inequality, so the two objects are equal and `Equals` should return `true`. Here's an implementation that will hopefully explain this better:

```
public class DatabaseEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        // Turn a null answer into true: if the most derived class has not
        // eliminated the possibility of equality, this and other are equal.
        return BaseEquals(other) ?? true;
    }

    protected virtual bool? BaseEquals(object other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;
        if (GetType() != other.GetType())
            return false;

        DatabaseEntity databaseEntity = (DatabaseEntity)other;
        if (ID != databaseEntity.ID)
            return false;
        return null;
    }
}

public class Person : DatabaseEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    protected override bool? BaseEquals(object other)
    {
        bool? baseEquals = base.BaseEquals(other);
        if (baseEquals != null)
            return baseEquals;

        Person person = (Person)other;
        if (person.FirstName != FirstName || person.LastName != LastName)
            return false;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is obvious in hindsight and I think this is probably the best solution. It is safe, as the casting can't cause an exception (otherwise the base method would return false). Thanks.

Comment: The drawback to this solution is that often equality checks for reference equality first, and if this is true it does an early return. To implement this using this solution you'd have to go through every class.

Comment: @PaulRichards True! What comes to mind as a way to solve that is to change `Equals` in the base class to `return Equals2(other) ?? true;`, where `Equals2` (new) is inherited in this answer's way instead of `Equals`. `Equals2` returns `true` if `this` is definitely equal to `o` (e.g. reference equality), `false` if definitely not equal, and `null` if equality wasn't ruled out but isn't definite without checking derived classes. `Equals2` base calls would be `bool? eq = base.Equals2(other); if (eq != null) return eq; [other checks]`. If this sounds reasonable I'll write it up tonight (better).

Comment: How the hell is this marked as the answer? This is so much more convoluted than the solution he had in his question already...it does exactly what he was already doing in a more obtuse way. He still has to override a method in each class and he still has to do the conversion he was hoping to avoid, but he also has to worry about correctly doing all the other boilerplate you've introduced into each class. Was July 8th 2015 backwards day?

Comment: @PaulRichards I don't see how this answer improves upon anything you had and way overcomplicates everything. Your cast was already safe to do without worrying about exceptions because your base Equals method implementation only calls EqualsIgnoringID after it has checked the types of the objects.

Comment: @MikeMarynowski I agree, not sure what I was thinking here. Would definitely find a better answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy using generics:

```
public abstract class Entity<T>
{
  protected abstract bool IsEqual(T other);
}

public class Person : Entity<Person>
{
  protected override bool IsEqual(Person other) { ... }
}
```

This works fine for one level of inheritance, or when all the levels are `abstract` except for the last one.

If that's not good enough for you, you have a decision to make:

- If it's not all that common, it might be just fine to keep the few exceptions with manual casts.
- If it *is* common, you're out of luck. Making `Person` generic works, but it kind of defeats the purpose - it requires you to specify the concrete `Person`-derived type whenever you need to use `Person`. This can be handled by having an interface `IPerson` that's *not* generic. Of course, in effect, this still means that `Person` is abstract - you have no way of constructing a non-concrete version of `Person`. Why *wouldn't* it be abstract, in fact? Can you have a `Person` that isn't one of the derived types of `Person`? That sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: The `Person` code was just an example, I have about 25 classes which derive from `DatabaseEntity` either directly or indirectly.  Some of these cannot be abstract, they have instances - and are base classes themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is a variant of @31eee384 one's.

I don't use it's trinary abstract method. I suppose that if `base.Equals()` return `true`, I still need to perform the derived Equals checks too.

The drawback though is that you renounce to have the Reference Equality in base.Equals to propagate this "short-circuit" in derived classes Equals method.

Maybe there exists something in C# to "force to stop" the overriding somehow and "hard return true" when the reference equality is true without continuing the overridden derived Equals calls.

Also do note that following 31eee384 answer, we give up the template method pattern used by OP. Using this pattern again actually goes back to OP's implementation.

```
public class Base : IEquatable<Base>
{
    public int ID {get; set;}

    public Base(int id)
    {ID = id;}

    public virtual bool Equals(Base other)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Begin Base.Equals(Base other);");
    
        if (other == null) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        if (GetType() != other.GetType()) return false;
    
        return ID == other.ID;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return this.Equals(other as Base);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            // Choose large primes to avoid hashing collisions
            const int HashingBase = (int) 2166136261;
            const int HashingMultiplier = 16777619;

            int hash = HashingBase;
            hash = (hash * HashingMultiplier) ^ (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, ID) ? ID.GetHashCode() : 0);        
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "A Base object with ["+ID+"] as ID";
    }
}

public class Derived : Base, IEquatable<Derived>
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public Derived(int id, string name) : base(id)
    {Name = name;}

    public bool Equals(Derived other)
    {   
        Console.WriteLine("Begin Derived.Equals(Derived other);");
    
        if (!base.Equals(other)) return false;
    
        return Name == other.Name;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return this.Equals(other as Derived);
    }   
    
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            // Choose large primes to avoid hashing collisions
            const int HashingBase = (int) 2166136261;
            const int HashingMultiplier = 16777619;

            int hash = HashingBase;
            hash = (hash * HashingMultiplier) ^ base.GetHashCode();
            hash = (hash * HashingMultiplier) ^ (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, Name) ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0);        
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "A Derived object with '" + Name + "' as Name, and also " + base.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here is my [fiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/RjiQdf).